# printing the word that is written multiple times in the file 1 time

Tags: c

I have a file :

```
Johnny 
Alice
Maria
Luca
David
Alexander
Luca 
Alice
Maria
```

If the same name is multiple from the file, I want to print that name only 1 time.How can I do this=
? Thanks...

Comment: Do you have tried something on your behalf?

Comment: Hint: the same can be achieved by using `sort <file> | uniq` in linux shell. Can you mimic this?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Not quite. That would not work. It would be `sort <file> | uniq -d` to get the repeated lines.

Comment: @einpoklum I assumed the OP is asking to print all the names without repetition, but your interpretation can work too.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use brute force, because of engineering time is costlier than computational time.

```
arr = []
for name in file:
    if name not in arr:
       arr.append(name)
       print(name)
```

Well, the above code works in O(n*n) in the worst case. So if you want to improve your efficiency, you can use hashing.

See, implementing hashing is not difficult. But if I say that you cannot store all the distinct names in hashmap / RAM then we cannot implement hashing.

I have already implemented an idea of this modified hard question. Use two files. I will attach my written algorithm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can this please be rewritten such that it is not abusing the reader's internet traffic with these images? We don't allow images instead of text in questions, and it should be the same for answers.

Comment: OP indicated they want a solution in C. Also, I really can't imagine why you'd need three page of text to answer OP's question.

Comment: Well, the three extra pages were of modified question. If hashmap can't store all the distinct names then we have to use two files. And I assume, if you are a good programmer, you can implement the logic in any language. If not then ping me, I will write pseudo code. But I will not spoon-feed him.